# Assign a task in Microsoft dynamic CRM 2011 one week before expiry date

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am new with Microsoft CRM 2011, I can define a workflow for an entity,

How can I implement this scenario:

Assign a task to someone one week before the expiry date of the contract.

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to create a new in workflow task or assigning an existing task?

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference?

Comment: Sorry, I from Creating a new Task I mean 'Creating & Assigning a new Task'. Or you want to assign an existing task to someone. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @ Scorpion: You are welcome, I just want to assign a task to someone before the expiry date, either existing or new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Custom field (e.g. `new_taskreminder`) on Contract Entity to store date to execute workflow.
2. Populate the newly created field with (ContractEndDate - 1 Week). You can write a plugin to populate the field or Contracts are only created using CRM UI then you can write javascript as well.
3. Create a new Workflow and add the wait condition as below:

   Instead of Contract End Date, select the newly created field.
   [image]
4. Under the condition, create new record. Select task from dropdown. Set the properties as you want to assign the task to someone.
   [image]
5. Final workflow will look like this: Activate the workflow to make affect.
   [image]

**UPDATE**

**NOTE:**
If you want to run workflow on fixed 7 days before ContractEndDate. You don't need to create or populate custom field. You can write the wait condition as below:
But if you want to calculate the weekdays and holidays, then good to write a plugin or custom workflow activity. 
[image]

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks again, I am going to test your solution.

Comment: I created a workflow it will started 1 day before end of contract, also I created a test contract record that it's End Contract Date is tomorrow, the process started but why it's "Status Reason" is "Waiting" ?

Comment: Status will be in waiting until wait condition is not passed.

Comment: if you double click on the process, you will be able to that on which step its waiting on at the moment.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to do some study about workflows and processes. There are lot of internet resources available.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes maybe there are many reason. but this is important that you answer my question and your solution will be work properly, also I checked that and saw this Step description: None provided.